# Gather values of a column based on distinct values in another column

Tags: r

I got this df

```
structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), adm1 = c(5, 
NA, NA, NA, 20, NA, 30, NA, NA), adm2 = c(NA, 10, NA, NA, NA, 
21, NA, 35, NA), adm3 = c(NA, NA, 15, NA, NA, NA, NA, 40, NA), 
adm4 = c(NA, NA, NA, 20, NA, NA, NA, NA, 45)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

and I would like to get this using a simpler method

```
structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 3), adm1 = c(5, 20, 30), adm2 = c(10, 
21, 35), adm3 = c(15, NA, 40), adm4 = c(20, NA, 45)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grouped by 'id', `summarise` `across` the columns and if there are only NA return NA or else remove the NA's with `na.omit`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  summarise(across(everything(), ~ if(all(is.na(.))) NA else na.omit(.)))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 5
#     id  adm1  adm2  adm3  adm4
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     5    10    15    20
#2     2    20    21    NA    NA
#3     3    30    35    40    45
```

---

Or another option is `coalesce`

```
library(purrr)
df %>% 
   group_by(id) %>%
   summarise(across(everything(), ~ invoke(coalesce, as.list(.))))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 5
#     id  adm1  adm2  adm3  adm4
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     5    10    15    20
#2     2    20    21    NA    NA
#3     3    30    35    40    45
```

Comment: Why these give me error when I use it on data now? I am sure it did work sometimes ago but not working now. I am getting error "across must only be used inside dplyr verb"

Comment: @kamrankhan can you check your `packageVersion('dplyr')`

Comment: @kamrankhan i tested again on the same data.  It is working for me though

Comment: version dplyr 1.0.2 . Its working on the sample data but not on my actual data.

Comment: I used `1.0.6` for this

Comment: Unfortunately same error even after installing dplyr 1.0.7. across must only be used inside dplyr verb".

Comment: @kamrankhan `summarise` is one where it should work well

Comment: @kamrankhan I installed 1.0.7 and tested.  It is working fine for me with the data showed

Comment: I am using summarise(across(everything()...., I think the problem may be the everything() function from tidyr

Comment: It is from `tidyselect`.  I have `packageVersion('tidyselect')
[1] ‘1.1.1’`

Comment: Can you try adding `dplyr::summarise`

Comment: That worked finally. You are awesome mate.

Answer (score 1):

Base R using `aggregate` -

```
aggregate(.~id, df, function(x) na.omit(x)[1], na.action = 'na.pass')

#  id adm1 adm2 adm3 adm4
#1  1    5   10   15   20
#2  2   20   21   NA   NA
#3  3   30   35   40   45
```

Comment: This one worked for me but it convert all my column with NAs to factors.

Comment: Are your original columns factors? You may use `res <- type.convert(res, as.is = TRUE)` to convert the result to their respective types automatically where `res <- aggregate(.~id, df, function(x) na.omit(x)[1], na.action = 'na.pass')`